# Erro ao implementar Localization no Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, globalização

Estou traduzindo meu sistema, implementando o conceito de **Globalization** e **Localization**. Minha aplicação está em ASP.Net Core 5 e está funcionando bem. Porém, me deparei com um problema no momento de instanciar um controller dentro de outro controller.

Estou tentando instanciar o controller `CiclosDeVidaController` dentro da classe `MapaController`.

[image: CiclosDeVidaController]

Porém, para implementar o conceito de **Localization**, eu preciso chamar o construtor passando como parâmetro `IStringLocalizer<CiclosDeVidaController> localizer`, como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: IStringLocalizer localizer]

Neste momento ele não aceita criar uma instância do controller vazio.
Qual a forma correta de fazer essa implementação? Uma vez que para usar o **Localization** é preciso chamar o construtor passando como parâmetro `IStringLocalizer<>`.

Comment: Eu não sei responder sua pergunta especificamente, mas, pelas imagens que você postou me parece que o problema está acontecendo porque a classe `CiclosDeVidaController` não tem mais um construtor sem parâmetros, e na primeira imagem você está tentando criar um objeto chamando o construtor sem parâmetros dessa classe, `CiclosDeVidaController()`, que aparentemente não existe. Achei esse artigo agora que pode ser útil: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/make-content-localizable